# In Microsoft Dynamics CRM, how do I get the meaning of an attributemask value?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have no background in Microsoft Dynamics CRM and the company I'm at lost their one developer who was maintaining this system. There is a function app with some code I'm trying to understand. The intent of the code appears to be to determine the user who set a price discount to then either permit it or not. It gets the audit entities associated with the salesorder that contain a 115 in the CSV AttributeMask.

```cs
List<Audit> audit = myServiceContext.AuditSet.Where(a => a.ObjectId.Id == x.Id)
    .ToList();

audit = audit.Where(a => a.AttributeMask.Split(',').ToList().Contains("115"))
    .ToList();
```

I believe this 115 must represent the discount field, but I want to know where the past developer found this value.

I've found suggestions online for how to get these AttributeMask values with a name, like [this one](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2015/02/ms-crm-audit-database-table-details.html), from the stringmap table. I used XrmToolBox's FetchXML Builder to dump the entire table but it only goes from 0 through 113. Some suggest looking in MetadataSchema tables, but I can't find those tables, and saw suggestions that those are only available for on-premises CRM.

Where can I find the meaning of 115 and/or how did a past developer decide to use this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code queries the **Audit** table and selects the audit rows for the record identified by `objectid`. (This is the first line.) As you can read on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/audit?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) column `audit.attributemetadata` contains a CSV of the ColumnNumber metadata property of attributes.

In the second line the audit rows are filtered down to those containing updates to column 115 of the table the targeted record belongs to. You can lookup the name and other properties of this column by retrieving the entity metadata for the table. The `EntityMetadata` object has an array of `AttributeMetadata`. In this array you can find the desired attribute by searching its column number in property `ColumnNumber`. More information can be found on [MS Docs - AttributeMetadata.ColumnNumber Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.columnnumber?view=dynamics-general-ce-9).

Comment: Thank you. Based on your guidance I was able to use XrmToolBox's MetaData Browser tool to open SalesOrder metadata, choose the Columns tab, scroll over to the column named ColumnNumber, click it to sort, scroll down to the 115 I was looking for, and the name makes sense to be the discount price I was looking for.